# How to change styling for only one of same children depend on prop

Tags: reactjs, components

I am trying to implement star voting with font awesome icons,
on Product.js i have 2  component , problem is when i change styling for a component that has prop, naturally it changes other component because of querySelectorAll, so how can i change the class for only component which has props i pass.

Product.js

```
const [rating, setRating] = useState(0);
const ratingHandler = (e) => {
    setRating(e);
  };
 <Rating  handleRating={ratingHandler} />
 <Rating />
```

for first child i want to add some styling like when i mouse over star ,it lights up etc. So i want to make it based on handleRating props.
Rating.js

```
const Rating = (handleRating = false) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (handleRating) {
      hover();
    }
  }, []);

 function hover() {
    const spans = document.querySelectorAll(".ratinger span:not(.texting)");
    console.log(spans);
    spans.forEach((spanon) => {
      const onStar = parseInt(spanon.dataset.value, 10);
      spanon.onmouseover = () => {
        spans.forEach((span) =>
          span.dataset.value <= onStar
            ? span.classList.add("hover")
            : span.classList.remove("hover")
        );
      };
      spanon.onmouseout = () => {
        spans.forEach((span) => {
          span.classList.remove("hover");
        });
      };
      spanon.onclick = () => {
        spans.forEach((span) =>
          span.dataset.value <= onStar
            ? span.classList.add("onclick")
            : span.classList.remove("onclick")
        );
        handleRating(parseInt(spanon.dataset.value, 10));
      };
    });
  }
```

i didnt add unnecessary parts on below i have icons within a div.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
const spans = node.querySelectorAll('...');
```